# How to convert Map of Map into list in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a map of the map. I have to convert into a list of an object using lambda. I am trying to convert with Java 8.

```
 private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Movie>> movies; // given

 List<Movie> movies // expected
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use declarative solution by using stream API like that:

```
List<Movie> movieList = movies.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(s-> s.getValue().entrySet().stream())
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I am using a flat map but doing a mistake not making type same but you make it entrySet. nice solution Thanks

Comment: OR `movies.values().stream().flatMap(m->m.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Okay I think, I am doing the mistake of not doing stream inside flapMap. now got it

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could call `Map#values` and avoid some lambda expressions, which could make your snippet more readable:

```
List<Movie> movieList = movies.values()
                                .stream()
                                .map(Map::values)
                                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a single collection of `Movie` objects from the wrapping map, `flatMap` should be applied to the collection of values:

```java
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Movie>> movieMap; 

List<Movie> movies = movieMap.values().stream() // Stream<Map<Integer, Movie>>
        .map(Map::values)  // Stream<Collection<Movie>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Movie>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, the resulting list is likely to contain duplicate movies.
If the redundant duplicates  need to be filtered, then `distinct` operation should be applied before `.collect`:

```java
List<Movie> distinctMovies = movieMap.values().stream() // Stream<Map<Integer, Movie>>
        .map(Map::values)  // Stream<Collection<Movie>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Movie>
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or the result may be collected into a set using `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`:

```java
Set<Movie> movieSet = movieMap.values().stream() // Stream<Map<Integer, Movie>>
        .map(Map::values)  // Stream<Collection<Movie>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Movie>
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I don't want unique. if someone using it please declare equal and hashcode